# What is faster: SUM over NULL or over 0?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, query-performance

I have a query like this:

```
select sum(case when col1=@arg1 then value else null end) from t
```

Is there, performance-wise, a difference to use `0` instead of `NULL` ? Like this:

```
select sum(case when col1=@arg1 then value else 0 end) from t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the below test I consistently found `NULL` is slightly faster.

```
   SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
   DECLARE @i int = null; /*Or set to zero*/

   WITH 
    E1(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    )                                       -- 1*10^1 or 10 rows
    , E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)   -- 1*10^2 or 100 rows
    , E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)   -- 1*10^4 or 10,000 rows
    , E8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E4 b)   -- 1*10^8 or 100,000,000 rows

    SELECT SUM(@i) FROM E8 
    OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

On average by 608ms to aggregate 100,000,000 values. (i.e. 6 nanoseconds per aggregation).

The `NULL` one spends more time in

```
sqllang.dll!CESRunTimeErrorSink::SetAggFnSkippedNull
```

Presumably setting the flag that leads to the message

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation.

But overall seemed quicker (elapsed times in ms below).

```
+---------+--------+------++-------+
|         |  NULL  |  0   || Diff  |
+---------+--------+------++-------+
| Trial 1 | 7027   | 7592 || 565   |
| Trial 2 | 6981   | 7743 || 762   |
| Trial 3 | 7451   | 8015 || 564   |
| Trial 4 | 6997   | 7591 || 594   |
| Trial 5 | 7018   | 7574 || 556   |
+---------+--------+------++-------+
| Avg     | 7094.8 | 7703 || 608.2 |
+---------+--------+------++-------+
```

Of course in this case (where all the input is `NULL`) they return different results and you would need an `ISNULL(SUM(@i),0)` if you wanted to treat the two interchangeably.

Comment: can you provide version of your sql server instance? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Devart RTM version of SqlServer 2014.

Comment: on 2012 sp3 get the similar results. thanks for this tip

Comment: Thanks, great script! Tried it on our server (2008r2) with 5 passes each, here we have in average 11753ms vs 12699ms, so that's 8.04% slower or 7.44% faster. Your average result is 8.58% slower or 7.91% faster, so that's similar!

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @type CHAR(2) = 'U'

-- [Expr1042] = Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN [Expr1048]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1049] END)

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = @type THEN 1 END)
FROM sys.objects

-- [Expr1042] = Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN [Expr1048]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1049] END)

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = @type THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM sys.objects

-- [Expr1042] = Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN [Expr1048]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1049] END)

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = @type THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM sys.objects
```

results:

```
Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1556, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 7 ms.

Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1556, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 6 ms.

Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1556, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 7 ms.
```

so... answer - similar (if we talk only about performance)